# Is there a way to restore multiple snapshots at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, restore, snapshot

I have a cluster of 4 EC2 Elasticsearch (version 7.7.1) nodes on AWS (including a master).
A Snapshot (incremental) of all indices is made daily.

This cluster being built on type "I" ec2 for good read/write performance , the storage is volatile : in case of cluster crash, all data is gone. That's not something I can change at this moment.

I simulated a cluster crash by terminating my instances, and rebuilding my cluster before I restore my daily snapshots in it.

I can't find a way to accelerate the restoration of snapshots on the new cluster.
The client I work for wants 14 days of data on the cluster. Snapshots being daily incremental, that means I have to restore 14 snapshots to recover all my data, one day at a time. I can't make ONE full restoration.

At each restoration, the data is being rebalanced between nodes according to the replication policy (1:1). I have to wait quite a long time between my restoration and the cluster status being green. For 500Go of data (which is nothing compared to the data we estimate in the future) : it took me more than 2 hours to restore all my snapshots.

During this process, all indices must be closed, but restoring a snapshot open some indices, so I have to close them all before restoring each snapshot...
Kibana and Logstash are sending/listening to the cluster, so I have to stop them in order to restore my snapshots quietly.

Is there any way to improve this ? I can't find a way to restore multiple snapshots at once.
Should I stop the rebalancing while the restoration is being made ?

I'm surprised I can't find anything on that, I must've missed something big :/
Any ideas, or experience feedback on that ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Snapshots being daily incremental, that means I have to restore 14 snapshots to recover all my data, one day at a time.

**This statement is not correct!** All you have to do is to restore the latest snapshot and that will restore all of your data.

Being incremental means that each snapshot contains only the data created since the last snapshot, but it also links to older data contained in older snapshots, but you don't have to care about that, just restore the latest one and you'll see you'll have all your data.

Comment: Oh, that's good news ! I was pretty sure I tested restoring the latest snapshot, and I had only the today data. I'll try again and make you a feedback, thanks !

Comment: Ok, let me know

Comment: Hey ! It's working ! The reason I thought it wasn't working is because of curator : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634853/difference-between-curator-cli-and-curator-action-files?noredirect=1&lq=1  I have this problem where it only snapshot my indices beginning with "." When I restored this partial data, thinking it was a full snapshot, the snapshot only contained the data of the day... Sorry for this mixed-up problem, it's now solved. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Val in above comment.
Even though elasticsearch is incremental in nature, internal architecture of snapshot is such that it makes sure content of snapshot is exact copy of cluster content when the snapshot starts.

So if you restore latest snapshot to cluster, then after restore completes you should have exact data in cluster that  present at the time of the snapshot creation.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ! Before i can test again, i'm stuck with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634853/difference-between-curator-cli-and-curator-action-files. Got to resolve that before I retry and I'll let you guys know, thanks again !